# Creating an npm module that can store a shared instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am looking to create npm library that can be initialized once with a set of keys and then reused throughout a project

This is an example of how I would like it to be used

In root component or page

```
import lib from "lib"

const libInstance = lib({someKey : "123"})
```

In another component called in the future...

```
import lib from "lib"

const libInstance = lib()


const aFunction = () => {
   libInstance.doSomethingUseful()
}
```

I have seen a lot of good examples where an npm library function is used to carry out unrelated tasks (e.g add/subtract) but unfortunately not much that can help me.

Comment: Your question is "How do build a thing that can retain information across files"?

Comment: Is the goal here that calling `lib()` without arguments just returns whatever `lib()` instance was previously created? Could be as simple as saving a singleton to a variable in that file.

Comment: @tadman Just having a look at singletons now, I think it will work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you do come up with a solution that works, add it as a self-answer for posterity and to share with others.

Comment: yeah, I definitely will do!

Answer (score 1):

Why not take the more common approach and have a specific file that your package references, similar to babel, jest, webpack, eslint, prettier, etc ?

```js
// node_modules/yash-lib
const config = require('../../.yashrc')
const lib = initLib(config)
module.exports = lib
```

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for some time, I came to this solution

```
let config: Config = {
key: null,
}

const Core = {
  config: () => {
    return config
  },
  initialize : (_config : Config) => {
    
      config = _config;
  },
}

export default Core
```

Using `core.Config()` returns the key, which I can use in other peer dependancy libraries.